# Spilt soup on my T400 keyboard and it turns itself off

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I accidentally spilled some soup onto my keyboard, and my laptop (Thinkpad T400) turned itself off, probably because of short-circuit. It can't be turned on now. I remove the power and the battery. How should I do now? Any hope to save my laptop? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do anything.  You spilled liquid on electronics that were powered up.  Worst yet, you spilled liquid organic material.  There is nothing you can do to repair the laptop.

Comment: For *any hope at all*, you'd have to do a full flush with pure water (flush, not soak), followed by a pure alcohol rinse. You want to get the conductive crap off, not dry it. But since it was powered on, chances are some IC has shorted and burnt out, in which case you're out of luck unless you design motherboards for a living and are *very* handy with a soldering iron.

Comment: Honestly, you're better off removing the hard drive and salvaging your data, if nothing else.

Comment: How was the soup?

Comment: Not to make fun but it happens... invariably followed by the standard face-palm.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have accidental damage protection from Lenovo :) If not, you'll almost certainly have to replace your laptop. "Spaghetti soup with tomato and olive oil" -- that'll be pretty rough on electronics, especially if it got in the vent and made contact with the motherboard or CPU.

You could take it to a repair shop, explain the problem, and see if they can attempt to clean it and *then* dry it (the procedure is very careful and precise; any wrong step could make the problem worse). They can also tell you whether there are some damaged components. You might have lucked out that only some components are damaged while others are fine. If that is the case, you could pay the repair shop to replace the damaged components.

But repair shop labor is expensive, so a repair plus a cleaning plus a diagnosis will probably run you a significant fraction of the cost of buying a new T400.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you still can save the soup :)
Was it internal keyboard or external?
What kind of soup did you spilt? Consistency. And let it dry for sure, but not on heat source.
You can use fan, but don't push breeze on laptop.

Comment: the keyboard default with T400. spagetti soup with tomato and olivve oil. You meant no hope? Will it be helpful if I use a hair dryer to blow cool air to it?

Comment: Not on it.It might make bigger harm. Better let if dry by it self if u don't have regular fan. Three days later try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTZds3NpTOc and clean it, look what you can use on internet.

Comment: @Tim - You can dry it all you want, the damage is already done, the electronics cannot be repaired at this point.